# How can remove unwanted files generated in laravel with functions name?

Tags: php, laravel

When i had run the migration code of role permissions, i got some error on the command line . But after my entire laravel created with some unwanted files.

[image]

The code used for role permission :

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"`

How can i revert back? Why its creating these files `($data['email'], 'btn, etc...)` on the variable names ?

Comment: Why not use git to reset the changes in files?

Comment: @Cerlin How will do that ? I am new on this and its in my local machine..

Comment: If this project is a git repo, open terminal, go to root of the project and run `git checkout .`

Comment: Not in get, am doing from scratch and added my on codes. Don't have git..

Comment: just delete these as you delete the normal files.

Comment: @AnujShrestha Yes, I done like that...